# Is it possible to convert a list of strings into a variable list of arguments?

Tags: javascript

I know that javascript functions can take an arbitrary number of arguments which can be accessed via `arguments[i]`. I'm wondering if it is possible to convert that array into individual arguments to send to another function that also processes a variable list of arguments.

I have the following extension to the string class that basically formats strings similar to how string.format() works in .Net.

```
String.prototype.format = String.prototype.format = function () {
    var s = this,
        i = arguments.length;

    while (i--) {
        s = s.replace(new RegExp('\\{' + i + '\\}', 'gm'), arguments[i]);
    }
    return s;
};
```

I have another function that needs to take a javascript object and send properties to be processed into a string. The properties are set by the calling function. Here is an example of the usage I am trying to get. I'm simply stuck at passing the properties through as individual arguments to the function above. Any ideas on how to come about this?

```
function doMything(){

    var myData = GetMyDataFromSomething(); // returns a javascript array of objects
    var myMessageFormat1 = 'Person with ID {0} name is {1} {2}';
    var myPropertyList1 = ['UserID', 'FirstName', 'LastName']

    var finishedStrings1 = formatTheString(myData, myMessageFormat1, myPropertyList1);
    // ex. Person with ID 45 name is Jake Gyllenhal; Person with ID 46 name is Bob Barker

    var myMessageFormat2 = '{0} is from {1}, {2}';
    var myPropertyList2 = ['FirstName', 'City', 'State']

    var finishedStrings2 = formatTheString(myData, myMessageFormat2, myPropertyList2);
    // ex. Jake is from Phoenix, AZ; Bob is from San Diego, CA
}

function formatTheString(data, formatString, propertyList){
        var myStrings = [];
        data.forEach(function(item){
            myStrings.push(item.format(propertyList)); // this doesn't work because the object is passed as a single argument
        };

        return myStrings.join('; ');
}
```

Comment: `anotherfunction.apply(context, arguments);` --- is this what you want?

Comment: "".format will be native soon, i would use a different name...

Comment: @dandavis good point. I will rename to something like formatText until string formatting is standardized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`apply`(see MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

```
var yourArguments = ['foo', 'bar'];

formatString.format.apply(formatString, yourArguments);
// equivalent to 'formatString.format('foo', 'bar')
```

So, your function could be:

```
function formatTheString(data, formatString, propertyList){
        var myStrings = [];
        data.forEach(function(item){
            myStrings.push(item.format.apply(item, propertyList));
        };

        return myStrings.join('; ');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The other answers are correct, but just to explicitly show the `arguments` chain:

```
function one() {
    two.apply(this, arguments);
}

function two() {
    console.log(arguments);
}

one("one", "two", "three");
```

Prints:

```
["one", "two", "three"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Use `apply()`

```
   var args = ['arg1', 'arg2'];
   fn.apply(this, args);
```

is equivalent to

```
   fn('arg1', 'arg2');
```

Comment: Not sure why this was down-voted, my guess is that it's because the two are not technically equivalent. Using `apply` lets you specify the `this` context, which here you have set to the callers `this`. However, the invocation of a function from scope (versus from a property of an object) will have `this` pointing to `window` (the global object).

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add this as my final working solution in hopes that it will help someone. There were some logical errors on my original thought in the OP.

```
var MyClass = {

    loadSupportArticles: function() {
            var itemMarkupFormat = '<tr class="row-link single-cell"><td><a href="support-page.html/{0}">{1}</a></tr>';
            var $supportAriclesList = $('#support-panel tbody');

            this.populateTableFromAjaxResult(
                '/support/Popular',
                $supportAriclesList,
                itemMarkupFormat,
                ['ArticleId', 'Title']);
        },

    loadUsers: function() {
            var itemMarkupFormat = '<tr class="row-link"><td><a href="edit-user.html/{0}">{1}</a></td><td>{2}</td></tr>';
            var $userSummaryList = $('#users-panel tbody');

            this.populateTableFromAjaxResult(
                '/accountuser/AccountUsersAsync',
                $userSummaryList,
                itemMarkupFormat,
                ['Id', 'Name', 'Type']);
        },

    // the part you guys helped with
    getListItems: function(data, formatString, propertyNames) {
        var completeList = [];

        // for each data item
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

            // get values for each argument
            var args = [];
            for (var j = 0; j < propertyNames.length; j++) {
                var propertyName = propertyNames[j];
                args.push(data[i][propertyName]); // e.g.  data[0]["PropName"]
            }

            // apply the template
            completeList.push(formatString.format.apply(formatString, args));
        }

        return completeList.join('');
    },

    populateTableFromAjaxResult: function(url, $target, formatString, propertyNames) {
        $target.empty();

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'GET',
            accept: 'application/json',
            success: function(data) {
                var formattedData = MyClass.getListItems(data, formatString, propertyNames);
                $target.append(formattedData);
            }
        });
    }
}
```